# Combining Not Intersect, Target.Parent.Range and Worksheets.Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am aiming to add VBA that hides or shows rows depending on whether a user clicks on a specific cell that needs to loop many times.

I was wondering how to possibly combine Target.Parent.Range with Worksheet.Cells so that I can write a loop for it rather than repeating the code multiple times. The below code works fine but seems pretty inefficient:

```
'Hide1
    If (ActiveSheet.Name = "Dashboard") And Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("G38")) Is Nothing Then
        If Rows("40:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            Rows("40:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("G38").Value = "Hide"
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        Else
            Rows("40:47").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("G38").Value = "Show"
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        End If
    End If

'Hide2
    If (ActiveSheet.Name = "Dashboard") And Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("G48")) Is Nothing Then
        If Rows("50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            Rows("50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("G48").Value = "Hide"
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        Else
            Rows("50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("G48").Value = "Show"
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        End If
    End If
```

This will need to be repeated 10's of times as buttons are located at similar intervals down the sheet, so looping makes the most sense. Any help would be of great help as my attempts to combine the two functions have failed thus far.

Comment: You can use `Target.Parent.Cells`. Also to note, if this code is inside a worksheet change event, you can use `Me` instead of `Target.Parent`

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be shortened to this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim buttonRng As Range, hideRng As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set buttonRng = Target

    ' Add in your ranges into this If statement
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G38")) Is Nothing Then
        Set hideRng = Me.Rows("40:47")
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G48")) Is Nothing Then
        Set hideRng = Me.Rows("50:57")
    Else
        Set hideRng = Nothing
    End If

    If Not hideRng Is Nothing Then
        With hideRng
            .Hidden = Not .Hidden
        End With

        buttonRng.Value2 = IIf(buttonRng.Value2 = "Show", "Hide", "Show")
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You could add an additional sheet in with a list of the button location addresses and the range for them to hide.

[image]

You will need to set column `B` to text

and then use the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim buttonRng As Range, hideRng As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set buttonRng = Target

    With Sheets("Button Hide Range").Columns(1)
        Set hideRng = .Find(Target.Address(False, False))
    End With

    If Not hideRng Is Nothing Then
        With Me.Rows(hideRng.Offset(0, 1).Value2)
            .Hidden = Not .Hidden
        End With

        buttonRng.Value2 = IIf(buttonRng.Value2 = "Show", "Hide", "Show")
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This sheet can then be hidden or set to xlVeryHidden if desired so it is not viewable by the end user.

Or if all of the rows to be hidden are the same offset away from the buttons you could use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim buttonRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' i = row of first button to row of last button. Assuming each button is 10 rows apart from the previous
    For i = 38 To 78 Step 10
        If buttonRng Is Nothing Then
            Set buttonRng = Me.Range("G" & i)
        Else
            Set buttonRng = Union(buttonRng, Me.Range("G" & i))
        End If
    Next i

    If Not Intersect(Target, buttonRng) Is Nothing Then
        ' Assuming rows to be hidden are starts 2 rows away from button and ends 9 rows away
        With Me.Rows(Target.Offset(2).Row & ":" & Target.Offset(9).Row)
            .Hidden = Not .Hidden
        End With
        Target.Value2 = IIf(Target.Value = "Show", "Hide", "Show")
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```